# Why doesn't Math.pow return me the correct value?

Tags: java

I am trying to get the correct value for:

```
double poweredValue = Math.pow((1.1),(1 / 365));
```

Using my scientific calculator I get **1.0002611578760678121616866817054‬**. But Math.pow returns a **1**.

How do I get the full value returned?

Comment: Use 1 / 365d or 1 / 365.0

Comment: 1/365 is 0 (integer division).

Comment: I learn something everyday! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double poweredValue = Math.pow((1.1),(1 / 365.0));
System.out.println(poweredValue);
```

Output -
1.0002611578760678